# Alliances (factions), completely separate areas, except for the PVP zone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In Elder Scrolls Online, I started my character in the Ebonheart alliance. Now I'm level 20 and have visited into neighbouring areas out of curiosity, discovering level 48 characters and similar. By neighbouring areas I am still talking about the areas in the Ebonheart alliance, up to the right in the global map.

Does this mean that the areas I play in now, around Morrowind, for the Ebonheart alliance, is completely separate from the two other alliances?

In other words, are there 3 completely separate areas, and the only place I will meet characters from the other 2 alliances is in the PVP zone?

Or do I need to travel to one of the other areas in time to further level up and continue playing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the only time you will "meet" other factions is in Cyrodiil. Once you have completed the main story and reached Veteran rank 1, you will be given the option to play the Daggerfall covenant or Alderi Dominion quest lines. Even then you will be phased with other Ebonheart Pact players and see no other factions.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me, so could you please clarify for me?  I have seen low-level argonians and nords in the starting area for the Aldmeri Dominion, and they can't possibly have finished their main quest lines.

Comment: @crystalBlue If you had pre-ordered the game you got access to any race on any faction, I think if you upgrade to imperial edition you can do the same.

Comment: That does make a lot more sense, thank you.  I was unaware of that.

Comment: @Paralytic Nope, I got the Imperial edition but the only race that can play all fractions is an Imperial... So apparently it's preorder exclusive

Comment: Correction, you need to buy the Adventurer pack, not the Imperial edition, in order to unlock free faction choice for anything but Imperials.